# Can I output the Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 to a guitar amp?

Tags: amplifiers, audio

Since i don't own speakers, and I don't want to use Headphones, I was looking for an alternative solution.
I want to input my guitar and use amplitube and then output to the guitar amp.
I have a roland cube, it has the guitar input and an aux line in too.
My question is wich output of the Scarlett (headphones, speaker L, R) goes to wich input of the amp (aux line in, guitar in)?
and is it possible without damaging anything?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try both the guitar input as well the aux input on the Cube, they’re going to sound different. With the aux input you’ll bypass the Cube’s preamp processing. You can’t break the Cube with the Scarlett. The Scarlett’s headphone output is stereo and it could be connected to the aux input with a suitable stereo cable. Just don’t turn the phones level too high. That way you’ll get both sides of Amplitube’s stereo effects to the Cube, but it’s a mono speaker only so you won’t hear any of the stereo field. If you go to the Cube’s guitar input, connect the Scarlett’s left or right output to the Cube’s input.

Since the Cube is a guitar amp with a speaker, you might want to bypass Amplitube’s speaker modeling and maybe use its preamp and stompbox pedal effect modeling only, maybe power amp modeling as well. The Cube will provide the speaker part. I don’t know Amplitube so I can’t tell what these are called there.

Comment: Just to understand: I go out of Scarlett headphone and plug it to amp Line in aux. And if I plug into L or R of Scarlett I got L and R Mono

Comment: Each of the L and R outputs are mono. You could connect them to two separate amps if you wanted to. The headphone output is stereo and needs a TRS plug.